# React native MapView indoor level picker working on iOS but not Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

When using the mapView, part of the react-native-map library, the indoor level picker toggle works on ios devices, when zoomed in on certain buildings, but does not work at all on android devices.

```
   <MapView
  style={styles.mapStyle}
  provider="google"
  showsUserLocation={true}
  region={props.region}
  zoomEnabled={true}
  showsIndoorLevelPicker={true}
  showsIndoors={true}
  showsMyLocationButton={true}
/>
```

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by resizing the MapView component after a short delay, I can get the indoor floor picker to show up on Android. Here is an example with a functional component.

The same principle would apply for a class component, but you would use setState() instead.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';


import MapView, {
  Polygon,
  Polyline,
  LatLng,
} from 'react-native-maps';


export const Overlays = () => {

  const [currentMargin, setCurrentMargin] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCurrentMargin(0);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={{ marginBottom: currentMargin, ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
        showsIndoorLevelPicker={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
        provider={"google"}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 45.497284367030844,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0015644580909750516,
          longitude: -73.5790109820664,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0024069473147392273,
        }}
      >
      </MapView>
    </View >
  );

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  }
});

export default Overlays;
```

Here is the result!
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSWX1.png)

Hope this helps.